# Navigation design pattern for showing current state

Tags: design-patterns, breadcrumbs, accordion

I'm looking for a high-level navigation design pattern that will also show the current navigational state. (Ex: Dashboard, invoices, settings, etc...) I am currently planning on using an accordion menu and breadcrumbs, but this seems really clunky. Anyone know of a good way to combine these? Other suggestions?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "current state": location in the app, items the user already filled out, etc.

Comment: (Edited the question a bit.) I mean showing where the user currently is in the application / what page they're on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps an interactive breadcrumb? Lonely Planet does a good job of making the breadcrumb more useful by combining it with menu options.
[image]

Comment: Interesting! I hadn't thought to make the breadcrumb more interactive. +1

Comment: It's a useful technique in some situations. Cranfield University is another example that springs to mind - there are more. http://www.som.cranfield.ac.uk/som/p10666/Research/Events

Comment: Thanks for the other example -- it's way better than the Lonely Planet one. I like the auto-drop down.

Comment: This is the design I ended up using. Marked as accepted. (I'd love to hear more thoughts though!)